# Error in Flutter: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter

This class in main.dart won't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyFlutterApp()

  );
}

class MyFlutterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MaterialApp(
        title: "My Flutter Application",
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("hello"),),
          body: Material(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              child:  Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hello Flutter",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0,),
                  )
              )
          ) ,
        )
    );

  }

}
```

That's it. The entire main.dart.
The *class* won't work.
It shows:

```
Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../flutter_projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`build` method has to return a widget. Try

```
class MyFlutterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "My Flutter Application",
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("hello"),),
          body: Material(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              child:  Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Hello Flutter",
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0,),
                  )
              )
          ) ,
        )
    );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the lines:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MaterialApp(
        title: "My Flutter Application",
```

The problem is that the line

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
```

is a function and as pretty much in any language function signature the return type of function is the very first part which here is `Widget`.

As dart is a statically typed language and if some method/function has a return type you need to return is else it throws compile time error.

Whereas in you function you do not return anything you are just declaring the `MaterialApp` instance. What exactly should have be done was either to user `return` before `MaterialApp` which should look like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return MaterialApp();//please not these semicolons are must if using return keyboard
}
```

or

The second work around is to use fat arrow operator `=>` for inline returns. Which looks like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp()
```